# Power bases for unramified extensions of an affine genus 0 curve.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

$\newcommand{\Qbar}{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}}$

Let $R = $ Spec $\Qbar[x,\frac{1}{x-1},\frac{1}{x-2}]$, with fraction field $K$.

Let $f$ be integral over $R$.

Suppose the integral closure $\tilde{R}$ of $R$ in $K(f)$ is *unramified* over $R$. Must $\tilde{R} = R[f]$?

Comment: I don't know a counterexample offhand, but the answer must surely be no. That said, you can factor in $R[\alpha]$ as though it was $\widetilde{R}$. Is that not good enough?

Comment: @AlexYoucis My intuition is basically this. Certainly $R[\alpha]$ is finite flat surjective over $R$. Further, $\tilde{R}$ is finite etale over $R$. If $R[\alpha]$ were unramified over $R$, then it would be etale over $R$, hence regular, hence integrally closed. I'm having trouble believing that $R[\alpha]$ could be ramified over $R$, given that $\tilde{R}$ is unramified over $R$.

Comment: Could you explain why think this is the case? Clearly if $R[\alpha]$ was Dedekind itself then I see why you wouldn't expect this: if $\mathfrak{p}$ ramified in $R[\alpha]$ then evidently it would in $\widetilde{R}$ by looking at the factorizations, but why do you not expect this here? I mean, let's look at the sequence 

$$\Omega^1_{R[\alpha]/R}\otimes_R\widetilde{R}\to \Omega^1_{\widetilde{R}/R}\to\Omega^1_{\widetilde{R}/R[\alpha]}\to 0$$

Without the injectivity on the left I don't see how you should conclude? I also did some calculations in SAGE which seem to show that this certainly fails

Comment: at least for number fields. Am I being crazy?

Comment: @AlexYoucis I do suspect it fails for number fields, but I'm hoping it's because of inertia or something else that goes away when you look at stuff over Qbar

Comment: @AlexYoucis wanna go into chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30289/discussion-between-alex-youcis-and-oxeimon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found a counterexample in the simplest example that could work.

Let $R = k[x]$, and let $f$ satisfy the polynomial $f^2 = x^2(x-1)$. This is precisely the equation of the nodal cubic, with node at $(x,f) = (0,0)$, and thus is not integrally closed.

Note that $R[f]$ is degree 2 over $R$, and ramified above $x = 0,x = 1$. The ramification above $x = 0$ is precisely the node.

On the other hand, to normalize, one adjoins $t := f/x$ to $R[f]$. Then $t^2 = x-1$, so the normalization is just $R[t]$ satisfying the relation $t^2 = x-1$. But note that over the $x$-line, this is only ramified at $x = 1$, so by inverting $x-1$, we find that $R[t]$ is unramified over $R[(x-1)^{-1}]$. Thus, we have the sequence
$$\text{Spec }R[t]\longrightarrow\text{Spec }R[f]\longrightarrow\text{Spec }R[x]$$
where the composite is ramified only above $x = 1$, but the second map is ramified above both $x = 0$ and $x = 1$. The "extra ramification" at $x = 0$ comes from the node, which is resolved when you take the integral closure, since normalization basically "splits the node in 2", so the answer is no because $R[t] \ne R[f]$.

Comment: Isn't not in the form you wanted? That you mentioned in chat?

Comment: @AlexYoucis what do you mean? If you're referring to removing 3 points, the idea is that you can simply remove the point $x = 1$, and also say $x = 2$ (and $\infty$). Once you do this the composite is unramified but the second map is ramified.